# Stream Analytic to PowerBI complains about PowerBIOutputAdapterTransientError

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-stream-analytics, cortana-intelligence

I'm outputting a Stream Analytics job to PowerBI.com. It successfully sends the first 11-100 messages just fine, but after which it fails. In the operational log it says the operation "failed to send events" and is categorized as a "PowerBIOutputAdapterTransientError" without much other information. What are the symptoms of this type of error?

Messages are still going through Event Hubs but all operations seem to be haulted on the PowerBI side.

Comment: It magically started working today without me changing anything. I guess it must have been a service issue that occurred yesterday. (Though a Microsoft Service employee said that the bug might be the result of the dataset being too big.)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was a transient service issue.